# Simulation in java using priority queues

Tags: java, events, simulation, modeling

I've been asked to simulate the events for a store with one counter in java using a priority queue. Where a person is being served and if someone arrives during this time i increment the number of people in the queue.I figured out that I have to use Comparator but so far it seems like i can only use comparator for sorting and not for queuing and DE-queuing events.

Comment: With the information you've given, a normal queue is most appropriate. Where does the priority part kick in?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There is a PriorityQueue class in the JDK. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: @ Jeroen Vannevel weve been asked to use them and along with them the poll() function.

Comment: @AbhishekHerle: You should probably figure out the reason first so you know what exactly is being expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a discrete event modeling perspective, you use a priority queue to schedule the sequence of events that drive the system.  You can find a [tutorial paper](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc06papers/001.pdf) on how to do  this, along with a Java implementation for a single server queue with exponential interarrival and service times, in the Winter Simulation Conference paper archives.

Comment: Can you tell me how they to be scheduled?

Comment: @AbhishekHerle: It's all in that tutorial paper, I promise.

Answer (score -1):

Problem statement you have mentioned you can implement it using a simple Queue, I could think of following design.

1. Queue - Which will hold list of persons.
2. Thread1 - Reads arriving persons and add Person into Queue
3. Thread2 - Removes from the Queue for processing
4. Size of Queue will give you number of persons in Queue

If you are working on collections and you need to sort objects then you need a compartor, but given the problem statement, looks like there is not need for sorting.

Cheers !!

Comment: i am supposed to use an event list that holds the arrival times and compare it to the departure times of the previous customer.