# Priority Queues in discrete event simulation and modelling

Tags: java, events, simulation

I have been asked to write a program in Java for a single server system, where the rate of arrival is continuously distributed. I have been asked to do this using priority queues. But I don't understand the need for it. Won't a normal FCFS queue suffice. How do I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321619/simulation-in-java-using-priority-queues

Comment: @pjs sorry should have read through that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a discrete event simulation the events usually need to be processed in timestamp order (virtual time order), not in arrival order. The priority queue is used to keep the events in timestamp order.

Comment: in that case how do you use the comparator?

Comment: a comparator is used to keep the queue in priority order.